# Running apt-get in and out of Anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, cuda, anaconda, apt-get

I am constructing deep learning environment with anaconda on my ubuntu system.
And I'm totally new with Anaconda.
I created an environment like

```
conda create -n darkflow python=3.6
source activate darkflow
pip install ...
...
```

when I install cuda in my conda environment *darkflow*,

```
apt-get install cuda-8-0
```

I start to wonder if I only installed cuda in my *darkflow* environment or I also have it on my ubuntu system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you've installed `cuda` from the official Nvidia repository.

`apt-get` will install it system-wide indeed, and `cuda` will be available from any environment, whether it's the system's python installation, or any python virtual environment.

What you've installed in your conda virtual environment are the python libraries that leverage the (C++) libraries installed from `apt-get`

Comment: what if I jump out of conda env, and install cuda, is cuda also avariable in each of my conda env?

Comment: If I understand it right, whether you run apt-get in any virtual environment or out of virtual environment, all the apt-get installations are system-wide variable?

Comment: That's it, yes!